# missing FROM-clause entry for table on postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to join two tables (PostgreSQL), but it is returning the following error:

missing FROM-clause entry for table "databaseone"

```
SELECT databaseone.*, COUNT(databasetwo) AS total_items
FROM databaseone
LEFT JOIN databasetwo ON (databaseone.id = databasetwo.item_id)
GROUP BY databaseone.id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Can someone explain the reason for the error and how to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can explain that error message. It does not apply to the code you present.

There must be something else going on that's not in your question.

Comment: sorry my friend... It's my fault... I wrote the code with a parenthesis out of place, already fixed it, if you can help, I will be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: @jsNew: Those parentheses are just noise and do not change anything. There is no missing FROM-clause entry.

Comment: forget that... it's just the parenthesis out of place... but, thanks anyway... your comment helped me to see it and now my db is running!